# Full outer join not working as I expect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
select *
from [dbo].[Revenue_PL_S_F_M] rsfm
  full join [dbo].[Expense_Misc_Variable] emv 
    on emv.FISCYR = rsfm.FISCYR
    and emv.FISCPER = rsfm.FISCPER
    and emv.Warehouse = rsfm.Warehouse
    and emv.Customer = rsfm.Customer
where RSFM.FISCYR = 2017 
  and RSFM.FISCPER = 1 
  and RSFM.GLGroup = 'M'
```

There are 3 rows in emv, 1 that doesn't have a matching rsfm.customer.  This line is not being added to the view.

Thanks in advance
Gerry

Comment: Your WHERE is preventing it from being included.

Comment: Ok, so is there another way to get what I need?

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` is limiting your join. Either move the `where` to the join condition, or use a derived table for `rsfm`.

```
select *
from  [dbo].[Revenue_pl_S_F_M] rsfm
  full join [dbo].[Expense_Misc_Variable] emv
    on emv.fiscyr = rsfm.fiscyr
    and emv.fiscper = rsfm.fiscper
    and emv.Warehouse = rsfm.Warehouse
    and emv.Customer = rsfm.Customer
    and rsfm.fiscyr = 2017 
    and rsfm.fiscper = 1 
    and rsfm.glgroup = 'M'
```

or

```
select *
from  (
  select * 
  from [dbo].[Revenue_pl_S_F_M]  
  where fiscyr = 2017 
    and fiscper = 1 
    and glgroup = 'M'
    ) rsfm
  full join [dbo].[Expense_Misc_Variable] emv
    on emv.fiscyr = rsfm.fiscyr
    and emv.fiscper = rsfm.fiscper
    and emv.Warehouse = rsfm.Warehouse
    and emv.Customer = rsfm.Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Full outer joins are quite tricky, especially when it comes to filtering.

I suspect that you might want:

```
select *
from [dbo].[Revenue_PL_S_F_M] rsfm full join
     [dbo].[Expense_Misc_Variable] emv 
      on emv.FISCYR = rsfm.FISCYR and
         emv.FISCPER = rsfm.FISCPER and
         emv.Warehouse = rsfm.Warehouse and
         emv.Customer = rsfm.Customer
where coalesce(RSFM.FISCYR, emv.FISCYR) = 2017 and
      coalesce(RSFM.FISCPER, emv.FISCPER) = 1 and
      coalesce(RSFM.GLGroup, emv.GLGroup) = 'M';
```

This returns matches between the tables when at least one "matching" row in either table matches the conditions you want.

My guess is, though, is that a full outer join might not be the best approach for whatever problem you are facing.  You might consider asking another question with an appropriate sample of data and desired results.